# How to use an asp.net web service for refreshing only small part of asp.net 4.0 web page without editing any other part

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I know how to write a web-service but until now I used them with always ready scripts. What I want to do this time is, have a web-service will return a string and I want to display this string in a part of webpage. That part may be inside an update panel or not. I know how to use jquery. So my question is how do I call a web-service every 5 seconds and update a part of webpage with the result of web-service. This update should not interrupt any part of the page and never cause post-back.

How can I do that?

asp.net 4.0 , c# 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page is already using updatepanels then you could reuse the ms ajax libraries  with no need for the jquery library at all.

javascript:

```
  function GetMyString() {
   // Call a static page method to get your string
   PageMethods.GetMyStringWebMethod(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
```

}

```
 function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
    $get('yourDivContainer').innerHTML = '<b>' + result + '</b>';
   setTimeout("GetMyString()", 5000); 
    }


function OnFailed(error, userContext, methodName) { }

function pageLoad() {
      // On initial load and partial postbacks, 
   GetMyString();
```

}

Page Method in your code behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetMyStringWebMethod()
    {

        return "the string";
    }
```

aspx:

change asp:ScriptManager to have EnablePageMethods="true"

If you're happy using jquery then just replace the Pagemethods call with an jquery.Ajax call passing in the GetMyStringWebMethod.aspx as the url and handle the string inset in the ajax success event.

Comment: thanks for great answer. but this fails :    PageMethods.GetMyStringWebMethod(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
  i only replaced PageMethods with my own class but it failed. how do i call webservice inside class ?

Comment: you need to add EnablePageMethods="true" to <asp:ScriptManager />

Comment: and then call "PageMethods.YourMethodName" - make sure the "YourMethodName" is a static method in the code-behind for the page and that it has the "[WebMethod]" attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with C# only - this has a significant client side portion, so you will need to use javascript.

You can use AJAX to poll the webservice and update a section of your page. Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) for repeating a call every 5 seconds.

Look at the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) API.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is what you're looking for :)

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) is a pretty good guide to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.setInterval` in Javascript to continuously poll the webservice.

```
setInterval(function() {
  // call the webservice and update the page with its response
}, 5000);
```

To call the webservice with jQuery, you can use the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or `get` functions:

```
$.ajax(
  url: ...
  data: ... input data
  success: function(response) { /* update your page with the response */ },
  error: function() { /* don't forget to treat errors */ }
);
```

Now, updating the page depends on what kind of response you got. Assuming you got a simple string (or HTML string) that you want to put inside a `div` element, you can do it like this:

```
// this is your success handler
$('#myDiv').html(response);
```

Comment: well this is the part i am asking for. inside of that function